# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для проверки в гуглформах

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть номер в формате XXX YY ZZZZ, где
ХХХ - могут быть цифры и заглавные буквы (з знака)
YY - только цифры (2 знака)
ZZZZ - цифры и заглавные буквы (4 знака).
Разделитель между ХХХ и YY пробел, также как и между YY и ZZZZ.

пробую так, но не выходит...

```
^[0-9A-Z]{3} \[0-9]{2} \[0-9A-Z]{4}$
```

А если я хочу ограничить количество цифр и букв, то будет вот так

```
 ^([0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}) ...
```

Comment: не понятно зачем вы слеши поставили в своей регулярке. `^[0-9A-Z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9A-Z]{4}$`

Comment: спс, все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё верно, за исключением того, что обратные слеши в данном случае не нужны:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9A-Z]{4}$
```

Они нужны для экранирования символов, к примеру под шаблон `\.` будут попадать только `.`, а не любые символы.

Comment: спс, что то я попамяти забыл когда слеши ставить нужно)